# Looking for the title of an epic movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

It's a futuristic Sci-Fi action movie from the 90's, and all I remember are some random stuff and the ending.

It ends (spoiler alert?) with the hero, a cowboy-ish kinda guy that was released from prison to help the world at the beginning of the movie, getting a hold of this remote that is claimed to "send humanity 100 years back" in terms of progress or technology (I think?) by some guy who's eyes plead the hero not to press the dreaded button.
The hero then looks at the guy, lights up a cigarette in an oh-so macho fashion with matches (old-fashioned), and presses it, implying he always preferred how things used to be with no technology etc.

Other than that I remember a scene with a submarine (?) and maybe the usage of the word "Alcatraz" maybe even in the title of the film, not sure of it though.

I watched this film more than 15 years ago so everything is a blur.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds an awful lot like [Escape from L.A.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116225/).  (Spoilers) At the end, Snake Plissken, who is a bit cowboy-like, definitely has a "remote" that he presses to destroy all electronics and reset society.  He was released from prison to save the world from a doomsday device and does light up a cigarette.  If I recall, Los Angeles was an Alcatraz-like island, after a big earthquake and he did have to be transported to the island in a submarine.

Comment: That's the one!!
thank you very much good sir!

Comment: Mark as definitive answer OP.

Comment: I like how Escape from LA was just referred to as "epic" :)

Comment: Thank you nelruk, I'm new here and so didn't notice the button.
@Lindsey - I was about 15 and do believe I enjoyed it very much.
see how goes when I give it another watch.

Comment: @Nitzan Pe'er  You also might be interested in watching [Escape from New York](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082340/) it's the first and more serious\darker  movie

Comment: O_O I didn't even know it existed.
Thanks a lot madmada.
I begin to seriously like this community...